# Sending message to Kafka producer shows message was successfully sent but there is nothing in the pipeline

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Came across a perplexing issue after upgrading our Kafka version from 2.5.1 to 3.2.0.

I am sending messages to a kafka producer as per the below.

```
final ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
   "my_topic",
   this.toString()
);
Future<RecordMetadata> kafkaResponse = producer.send(producerRecord);
// producer.flush();
String kafkaSuccessStatus = kafkaResponse.isDone() 
  ? "Message sent" 
  : "Message didn't send";
System.out.println(kafkaSuccessStatus);
```

The above prints out that the message has been successfully sent. However, the queue has no data inside of it. Further, I get a strange warning.

`org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

This seems incongruent with the message being sent. Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Just as a side note, this all previously worked in 2.5.1 but we have been forced to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is not checking whether a message was sent or not, it's checking if the Java future has finished executing or not.

You should use the version of `send()` that accepts a callback to get more feed-back about the asynchronous emission success (see https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-), or you could block with `get()` and either expect an instance of `RecordMetadata` or an exception to be blowing up your current thread.

Read the javadoc of the `send()` method above for more details.

Comment: This was able to fix it. Thanks!